# Gitlab Docker build: calling shell command in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables, gitlab

I'm trying to call shell command in [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/s.knape88/go-hello-world-k8s/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml), whose relevant parts are:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

...

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - GIT_TAG=$(git tag | tail -1)
    - GIT_TAG=$(/usr/bin/git tag | tail -1)
    - docker ...
```

However all top three shell command callings have failed, all with "command `not found`" error. The `git` command being failing is really odd, because it has to get the git repo first before start the `script` section. I.e., I can see that `git` is working, but I just can't use it myself.

Is there any way to make it working?

Comment: Are you sure `docker:latest` has `git` installed? Try adding `apt-get install -y git`.

Comment: [Turns out](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/9633df3ae8a88dfed9ba7f92e8a911249bbe4ec0/18.09/Dockerfile) `docker:latest` is based on `alpine:3.9` so you need `apk add --no-cache git`.

Comment: As you're using GitLab, there are special variables available to get the branch/tag/user/commit/etc details already available. Use those instead of installing Git!

Comment: @rebelution, if you meant `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` then please see my earlier comment that  I've tried and confirmed that it is not available for my specific case in OP.

Comment: @xpt - got it. are you creating a tag and experiencing this behavior? This is what I found in the documentation of GitLab
"**CI_COMMIT_TAG - The commit tag name. Present only when building tags**"

means - when you will push a commit to GitLab, then it will start a pipeline without CI_BUILD_TAG variable. When you make a tag on this commit and push this tag to GitLab, then another pipeline (this time for the tag, not for the commit) will be started. In that case CI_BUILD_TAG will be present.

Comment: Thanks @rebelution, they are valuable inputs. Would you like to expand it into the answer? As I'n not building tags in above .gitlab-ci.yml step, apparently the stage in .gitlab-ci.yml need to incorporate such change/requirement as well... I'll upvote for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see `git` working in separate steps because GitLab is probably doing it in another container. They keep your container clean, so you have to install dependencies yourself.

Since the image you're using is based on Alpine Linux, the command to install `git` is:

```
apk add --no-cache git
```

You can also skip the whole thing and use the [predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) if all you need is git information. `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` will contain the tag and `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` will contain the commit hash.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` in the answer please? The doc says it is _"commit tag name. Present **only when building tags**."_ Am I _building tags_ in above `.gitlab-ci.yml` step? Would I be able to use it in my step if not? Moreover, the doc doesn't say it is the latest tag, while I have lots of them. Which on will be `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`? Thx!

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with GitLab, but usually CI systems build on every commit and new tag. When it's building a tag, that variable will have that tag name. That's usually what people need the tag for in CI, so they can mark the version with the tag name.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, kichik. I've tried and confirmed that, for my specific case in OP, the $CI_COMMIT_TAG is empty.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation of GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), here is the definition of CI_COMMIT_TAG: 
*CI_COMMIT_TAG - The commit tag name. Present only when building tags*

means - when you will push a commit to GitLab, then it will start a pipeline without `CI_COMMIT_TAG` variable. When you make a tag on this commit and push this tag to GitLab, then another pipeline (this time for the tag, not for the commit) will be started. In that case `CI_COMMIT_TAG` will be present.

@xpt - thanks for the vote confidence and asking to write up this as an answer, hope this helps the community!

Comment: thanks, let me try it out and get back to you. So you are saying that by using `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, the above .gitlab-ci.yml in my OP will work without any more modifications, right?

Comment: I tried it just now, and it doesn't work, unless  .gitlab-ci.yml in OP is modified -- `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` always gives me my project name, never the tag name. Please make sure it works at your end before post any answer, not just you think it'd work. thx.

Comment: @xpt - thanks, edited the answer, will test it out and share if I find anything around it :)